# Jetty 9 deploy war with WebAppProvider

Tags: java, jetty, war, hotdeploy

I am trying to deploy a war or a directory named root.war.
My code is able to scan and run the war.
But I am not able to access any web services and keep receiving a 404 not found error.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong...
Thanks

```
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();            
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts, new DefaultHandler() });           

WebAppProvider webAppProvider = new WebAppProvider();
webAppProvider.setMonitoredDirName( combine( BUILD , STAGING ) );
webAppProvider.setScanInterval( 1 );            

DeploymentManager dm = new DeploymentManager();
dm.setContexts( contexts );            
dm.setContextAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$");
dm.addAppProvider( webAppProvider );        

embeddedServer.addBean( dm );            
embeddedServer.setHandler( handlers );

logAndDisplayInfo( "Attempting to start Jetty server");            
addConnectors( embeddedServer );
embeddedServer.start();
```

Following is the log dump I see after putting: server.dumpAfterStart(true);

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@25bbe1b6 - STARTING
 += qtp1291286504{STARTED,8<=37<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   +- 15 qtp1291286504-15-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 20 qtp1291286504-20-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 85 qtp1291286504-85-acceptor-0@172f494e-ServerConnector@7a3c99f1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
 |   +- 94 qtp1291286504-94-acceptor-0@61904002-ServerConnector@16b7e04a{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
 |   +- 19 qtp1291286504-19 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 17 qtp1291286504-17 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 76 qtp1291286504-76-acceptor-0@9f892f0-ServerConnector@3ec082a1{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9443} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
 |   +- 74 qtp1291286504-74 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 95 qtp1291286504-95 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 82 qtp1291286504-82-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 77 qtp1291286504-77 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 79 qtp1291286504-79 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 18 qtp1291286504-18-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 69 qtp1291286504-69-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 84 qtp1291286504-84-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 73 qtp1291286504-73-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 70 qtp1291286504-70 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 92 qtp1291286504-92 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 75 qtp1291286504-75-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 90 qtp1291286504-90 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 78 qtp1291286504-78-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 68 qtp1291286504-68 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 88 qtp1291286504-88 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 83 qtp1291286504-83 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 72 qtp1291286504-72 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 21 qtp1291286504-21 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)   
 |   +- 16 qtp1291286504-16-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 80 qtp1291286504-80-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 67 qtp1291286504-67-acceptor-0@6478ae7e-ServerConnector@18811c42{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:90} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
 |   +- jobs     
 += ServerConnector@7a3c99f1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@25bbe1b6 - STARTING
 |   +~ qtp1291286504{STARTED,8<=38<=200,i=2,q=0} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@55fe41ea - STARTED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@7f030c72
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@68d8ae27 - STARTED
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@18513c23 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@69ea9e1b keys=0
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@6be50b35 id=1 keys=0 selected=0 id=1
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@606b79f7 keys=0
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@ce2eaa7 id=2 keys=0 selected=0 id=2
 |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@6678dc4f keys=0
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@2166c48a id=3 keys=0 selected=0 id=3
 |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7610a6e1 keys=0
 |   += HttpConnectionFactory@1ce24091[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@304744a1{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:8443,[SecureRequestCustomizer@73385d3f]}
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]
 |   +- qtp1291286504-85-acceptor-0@172f494e-ServerConnector@7a3c99f1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}     
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@6cd7f381[o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}] - STARTED
 |   += o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war} - STARTED
 |       += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler2113133067==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 - STARTED
 |       |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@4e5d5ac1 - STARTED
 |       |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@70777a65
 |       |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@236fd411 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@402f61f5 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@6480a063 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   |   +- aliases=false
 |       |   |   |   |   +- dirAllowed=true
 |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCacheSize=256000000
 |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFileSize=200000000
 |       |   |   |   |   +- welcomeServlets=false
 |       |   |   |   |   +- useFileMappedBuffer=true
 |       |   |   |   |   +- acceptRanges=true
 |       |   |   |   |   +- etags=false
 |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFiles=2048
 |       |   |   |   |   +- redirectWelcome=false
 |       |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
 |       |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
 |       |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
 |       |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
 |       |   |   |   |   +- scratchdir=C:\Users\cs185225\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-90-<obsucredText>.war-_<obsucredText>.war-any-2397625917440130731.dir\jsp
 |       |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
 |       |   |   |   +- [/]=>default
 |       |   |   |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp
 |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@2f6f4ac4 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@727dcc64 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@49e62b17 - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += Charset Filter - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   |   +- requestEncoding=UTF-8    
 |       |   |   |   += MemberProfileExportServlet@dfb4eea2==com.<obsucredText>.presentation.servlet.ef.MemberProfileExportServlet,jsp=null,order=5,inst=true - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += <obsucredText>CSSDownloadServlet@8cb4a90e==com.<obsucredText>.presentation.servlet.ef.<obsucredText>CSSDownloadServlet,jsp=null,order=6,inst=true - STARTED
 |       |   |   |   += ServiceControlManager@36677185==com.<obsucredText>.enterprise.ServiceControlManagerServlet,jsp=null,order=2,inst=true - STARTED  
 |       |   |   |   += MemberLookupServlet@25bfad1==com.<obsucredText>.presentation.servlet.ef.MemberLookupServlet,jsp=null,order=6,inst=true - STARTED         
 |       |   |   |   +- [/*]/[]==0=>Charset Filter
 |       |   |   |   +- [/insightws/*]=>CXFServlet 
 |       |   |   |   +- [/initLogging]=>AAInitLog4j
 |       |   |   |   +- [*.do]=>action
 |       |   |   |   +- [/servlet/services]=>ServiceControlManager 
 |       |   |   |   +- [/tran/*]=>JerseyREST_TRAN  
 |       |   |   |
 |       |   |   +> null
 |       |   |   +> null
 |       |   |   +> null
 |       |   |   +> []
 |       |   |   +> /={TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[],None}, TRACE.omission={RoleInfo[],None}}
 |       |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache@288409f0[evict=-1,removeUnloadable=false,saveO<obsucredText>eate=false,saveOnInactiveEvict=false] - STARTED
 |       |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.NullSessionDataStore@7d685f4e[passivating=false,graceSec=3600] - STARTED
 |       |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@61eab26b[worker=node0] - STARTED
 |       += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@19ac93d2 - STARTED
 |       |
 |       +> WebAppClassLoader=Virtual BackOffice@58d75e99
 |       |   +- file:/S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/WEB-INF/classes/    
 |       |   +- file:/S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/WEB-INF/lib/common-annotations.jar 
 |       |   +- sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
 |       +> Systemclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |       |   +- java.
 |       |   +- javax.
 |       |   +- org.w3c.
 |       |   +- org.xml.
 |       +> Serverclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |       |          <jetty jars>
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jdt.
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.
 |       |   +- org.objectweb.asm.
 |       +> Configurations o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration@116fc29e
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration@2e426dd2
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration@1a0ffb9b
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration@67c0c90b
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration@8549c5f
 |       +> Handler attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |       |   +- javax.servlet.context.tempdir=C:\Users\cs185225\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-90-<obsucredText>.war-_<obsucredText>.war-any-2397625917440130731.dir
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern=.*/servlet-api-[^/]*\.jar$
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor=qtp1291286504{STARTED,8<=38<=200,i=2,q=0}
 |       |   +- org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath=S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\classes;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera-core-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera-extensions-json-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera-extensions-main-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera-i18n-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera-parser-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\apache-log4j-receivers-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\asm-2.2.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-api-1.2.7.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-awt-util.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-dom.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-svggen.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-util.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-xml.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\bcmail-jdk15on-1.47.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\bsf-2.3.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\bsh-2.0b4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\byte-buddy-1.6.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\byte-buddy-agent-1.6.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\cewolf.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\cglib-2.1_3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\common-annotations.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-chain-1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-cli.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.7.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-el.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-api.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.5.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool2-2.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-validator-1.3.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\cxf-bundle-2.2.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\ehcache-1.2.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\enterprise-core-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\ezmorph-1.0.5.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\groovy-all-2.4.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-annotations-2.1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-2.1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-databind-2.1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-4.1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-api-2.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jdbm-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jdom-1.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jdom.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\je-4.1.7.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jedis-2.6.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-bundle-1.18.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-json-1.18.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-test-framework-core-1.18.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-test-framework-http-1.18.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jettison-1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jfreechart-0.9.21.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jline-0.9.94.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jpos-1.8.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jra-1.0-alpha-4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\js-1.7R1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\json-smart-1.3.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jstl-1.0.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\jtds-1.2.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\junit-4.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\junitperf-1.9.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\lz4-1.2.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\mockito-core-2.6.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\mybatis-3.0.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\neethi-2.0.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\nimbus-jose-jwt-4.26.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\objenesis-2.5.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\oro-2.0.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\passkit4j-2.0.2-<obsucredText>.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\persistence-api-1.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\primrose.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\quartz-2.2.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\reflections-0.9.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-api-1.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\saxon-9.1.0.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\saxon-dom-9.1.0.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\saxon9-dom.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-jdk14-1.5.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-nop-1.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jms-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-2.5.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\standard-1.0.6.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\standard.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts-core-1.3.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts-el-1.3.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts-extras-1.3.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\urlrewritefilter.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\velocity-1.6.4.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\wss4j-1.5.8.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-apis.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-resolver-1.2.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xmlsec-1.4.3.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.3.1.jar
 |       +> Context attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory=org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory[decorators=1]
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE=org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources@35454c7a
 |       |   +- resourceCache=ResourceCache[null,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@50f3ba6a]@832219630
 |       |   +- rpcRouter=org.apache.soap.server.RPCRouter@1d806de6
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.action.MODULE=org.apache.struts.config.impl.ModuleConfigImpl@2b9d4b0
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.action.PLUG_INS=[Lorg.apache.struts.action.PlugIn;@4f541e67
 |       |   +- allAppenders=[org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender@2be50bba, org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender@3514ac7d, org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender@79c4f23b]
 |       |   +- org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT=org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@601cbd8c: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Jun 08 16:56:29 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.globals.MODULE_PREFIXES=[Ljava.lang.String;@160c7c42
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.action.SERVLET_MAPPING=*.do
 |       |   +- org.apache.struts.action.ACTION_SERVLET=org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet@15371de2
 |       |   +- serviceManager=org.apache.soap.server.ServiceManager@5503c7d
 |       +> Initparams o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@16a0ee18{/<obsucredText>.war,file:///S:/Ent/<obsucredText>/build/staging/<obsucredText>.war/,AVAILABLE}{S:\Ent\<obsucredText>\build\staging\<obsucredText>.war}
 |           +- javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX=.xhtml
 |           +- com.<obsucredText>.presentation.jsf.phaselistener.phaseTracker.cphase=ANY_PHASE
 |           +- com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews=0
 |           +- facelets.DEVELOPMENT=true
 |           +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext=com.<obsucredText>.presentation.resources.LoggingResources
 |           +- facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD=-1
 |           +- facelets.LIBRARIES=/WEB-INF/facelets/tag-af.xml
 |           +- contextConfigLocation=WEB-INF/beans.xml
 |           +- com.sun.faces.verifyObjects=true
 |           +- com.sun.faces.validateXml=true
 |           +- javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client
 |           +- org.ajax4jsf.handleViewExpiredOnClient=true
 |           +- org.richfaces.SKIN=<obsucredText>
 += org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager@5b5b53c6 - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider@2ec0ca83 - STARTED
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@3350ab4 - STARTED
 +- {}
 +- {}
 +- {}
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@61eab26b[worker=node0] - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper@7827d7b[interval=600000, ownscheduler=true] - STARTED
 |
 +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
```

Comment: Add `embeddedServer.setDumpAfterStart(true);` before you `.start()` and post the resulting dump output in your question.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : Thank you, I have edited the post and added the log dump. Please look into the same.